# Android App Links - Can I use different fingerprints with same package name for different builds?

Tags: android, android-app-links

Based on the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#web-assoc):

> sha256_cert_fingerprints: The SHA256 fingerprints of your app’s
> signing certificate. You can use the following command to generate the
> fingerprint via the Java keytool:
>
> keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
>
> This field supports multiple fingerprints, which can be used to
> support different versions of your app, such as debug and production
> builds.

and I assume it means I can use different build types with the same package name but different fingerprints. Since it an array.

Ex. 
com.my.app: "AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC" 
com.my.app.debug: "XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ"

I can juse use com.my.app and it should be smart enough to know that I use different build types based on the fingerprints?

So this is my json file example:

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.my.app",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        [
         "AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC:AA:BB:CC",
         "XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ:XX:YY:ZZ"
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

But it does not work. I also tried manually validating the doman and check the status.

I know it will work if I separate them in two different blocks... but I just really don't get why the document mentiones that. Or it is just a mistake on the doc?

Comment: Hi Arst, did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just use different blocks.